# MySQL: Not seeing how to select 1 column's value from a related table for related values from 2 columns in first table

Tags: mysql

I sometimes struggle describing simply and finding online odd things that I need to do in MySQL, so a web search and question title may need explaining.

Say I have a table named `routes` that have columns `origin` and `destination`, which each store  port code, and then another table named `ports` with column `country`.

The routes table records look like:

```
row1: origin -> ABC, destination -> DEF;
row2: origin -> GHI, destination -> JKL;
```

The ports table records look like:

```
row1: port -> ABC, country -> US;
row2: port -> DEF, country -> PR;
row3: port -> GHI, country -> JM;
row4: port -> JKL, country -> CN;
```

I need the output to look like:

```
origin -> ABC, destination -> GHI, og_country -> US, ds_country -> JM;
origin -> JKL, destination -> DEF, og_country -> CN, ds_country -> PR;
```

My psuedo-query looks like:

```
SELECT
    r.origin,
    r.destination,
    # p.og_country?
    # p.ds_country?? how?
FROM route r
ORDER BY r.origin, r.destination
```

I tried adding `LEFT JOIN ports p ON p.port = r.origin OR p.port = r.destination` (with the og_country and ds_country columns also selected), but that creates extraneous rows with duplicate data, like:

```
origin -> ABC, destination -> DEF, og_country -> US, ds_country -> null;
origin -> ABC, destination -> DEF, og_country -> null, ds_country -> PR;
```

Sub-selects work for origin country and destination country:

```
    (SELECT country FROM ports WHERE port = r.origin) AS og_country,
    (SELECT country FROM ports WHERE port = r.destination) AS ds_country,
```

However, the problem is that if I need to also fetch other values from the ports table (which I think I will eventually), there will be a lot of sub-selects that I want to try to avoid for efficiency reasons.

I was trying to do a UNION, but the problem is that the records across tables don't align in the same direction, where routes origin destination data are horizontal but ports countries data are vertical! Going through UNION examples and documentation, I'm not even seeing how to relate them.

Sorry I'm not good at explaining this... which is typical with me for SQL.